# Client want a field like PREFIX20100001

Tags: sql, mysql, calculated-columns

Client wants a field in the mysql DB to be composed of a prefix, the year, and a counter that resets each year.  PREFIX 2010 0001 ... PREFIX 2010 0734, then PREFIX 2011 0001.  Are there any mysql tricks to make that happen or do I keep track of the largest number used for each year.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can't create complex fields like that, but you could [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that would simulate it, based on something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('PREFIX', YEAR(NOW()), MOD(id, 10000)), ...
```

As long as there aren't more than 10,000 of these in a year, it'd be relatively safe as a "public" primary key. And on the plus side, if the id field is a normal auto_increment int in the background, you'd have a real primary key to work from.

Comment: how does the id part get reset to '0001' at the start of the new year?

Comment: ... also - what about leading zeroes for the id part?  The first value produced by the sample code would be 'PREFIX20101' I think.

Comment: True enough. Some magic based on REPEAT(), LENGTH() etc.. could handle the padding/formatting. The yearly reset would be harder. Possibly a server-side variable with a yearly event trigger to update with a proper offset/modulo... It'd need some experimentation, but the basics of this answer are most likely the best solution.